# Importing Values based on Date: Excel Macro

Tags: excel, pointers, copy-paste, vba

I am attempting to write a fairly intelligent macro for Excel. In this instance, I have two seperate workbooks that I am transferring information between. The first workbook has a listing of dates in column A followed by corresponding values in the following columns. Like so:

[image]

As you can see, the dates and values are not consistently entered. They are only available certain days. The current entries stop at the end of 2012. The point of this macro is to add new numbers each month.

an excerpt from Workbook 2 looks like this:
[image]

My current macro currently locates the correct values in workbook 2 and copies them to Workbook 1.
Which is great except for the possibility of inconsistent dates. Where there could be 15 days worth of values in the "CMP (3 YEARS)"section, but only 14 days worth in the "CMP (4 YEARS)" section. If I were to blindly copy those values over to sheet one they would not line up correctly. I would rather there be a calculated average if a date is missing

So to remedy this problem, I am attempting the current solution:

```
    'Grab 1 Month
Call Import("CMA/FIXED     (4 WEEKS)", "B1", DestinationWorkbook, ExportedWorkbook, 3, 2, False, DestinationDateRange)
```

The above method is called for each column of numbers to be located as well as for extracting the dates.

Allow me to explain what is supposed to be happening below. First the String to search for in the second sheet is passed in. this is used in conjunction with the x and y offset integers to locate the correct values. The DestinationSheetName is Workbook1 and ExportedDataSheetName is Workbook2. the isDateImport boolean is there to tell the method that this is the first import and all we are grabbing is the first set of dates that will be added to column A of Workbook1. The ByRef DateRange is a pointer to those dates after they have been copied and pasted to column A of Workbook1. So obviously when this is used for dates initially this is null.

from there we check to see what kind of import we are doing. If it is for dates we just do a simple locate, copy and past. If not, we attempt an inteligent import of the located values. The idea is to create a pointer to both sets of dates, The dates in Column A in workbook1 and the dates that correspond to the values we are copying. We want the paste location to be in the correct row for each date. I create both pointers and point them at the start of both date columns. In place of the copy paste code I am just printing to the debug window. if the pointers values match each other. After comparing the dates I attempt to increment the pointers to the next values in the columns of dates.

This works great for 2 dates and then I get an error when I try to increment the pointers.

What should I be doing to fix this error? or is there an easier way to do this?... I know pointers are a little overkill for Excel spreadsheets...

```
Sub Import(SearchString As String, PasteLocation As String _
, DestinationSheetName As Variant _
, ExportedDataSheetName As Variant, xOffset As Integer, yOffset As Integer _
, isDateImport As Boolean, ByRef DateRange)


Windows(DestinationSheetName).Activate
Set newSpot = Range(PasteLocation).End(xlDown)
newSpot.Select 'remove
Set newSpot = newSpot.Item(2, 1)

Windows(ExportedDataSheetName).Activate
Cells.Find(What:=SearchString, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Select


If Not isDateImport Then

    'intelligent import
    Set datesColumn = ActiveCell.Item(xOffset, yOffset)
    datesColumn.Select 'remove
    Set valuesColumn = datesColumn.Item(1, 2)
    valuesColumn.Select 'remove
    Set datesColumn = Range(datesColumn, datesColumn.End(xlDown))
    datesColumn.Select 'remove
    Set valuesColumn = Range(valuesColumn, valuesColumn.End(xlDown))
    valuesColumn.Select 'remove

    Set DateColumnPointer = datesColumn.Item(1, 1)
    DateColumnPointer.Select 'remove

    Set DateRangePointer = DateRange.Item(1, 1)
    Windows(DestinationSheetName).Activate
    DateRangePointer.Select 'remove

    For Each cell In valuesColumn
    If (DateColumnPointer = DateRangePointer) Then
        Debug.Print "Same"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Different"
    End If

    'increment Pointers
    Windows(ExportedDataSheetName).Activate
    DateColumnPointer = DateColumnPointer.Item(2, 1)


    Windows(DestinationSheetName).Activate
    DateRangePointer = DateRangePointer.Item(2, 1)

    Next
Else

'primitive import
Set cell1 = ActiveCell.Item(xOffset, yOffset)
If isDateImport Then
Set cell2 = cell1.End(xlDown)
Else
Set cell2 = cell1.End(xlDown).End(xlToRight)
End If
Set rng = Range(cell1, cell2)
rng.Select
rng.Copy

Windows(DestinationSheetName).Activate

If isDateImport Then
Range("W1").Select
Else
Range("V1").Select
End If

ActiveSheet.Paste

 'Add grabbed values
Set numbers = Range(Range("W1"), Range("W1").End(xlDown))
numbers.Copy
newSpot.PasteSpecial xlValues

End If

Windows(ExportedDataSheetName).Activate
Range("A1").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you set these variables globally outside the sub routine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use `set` in your increment pointers section to increase the range incrementally otherwise your only copying the values from the next cell up to the current one.

```
'increment Pointers 
Windows(ExportedDataSheetName).Activate 
Set DateColumnPointer = DateColumnPointer.Item(2, 1)

Windows(DestinationSheetName).Activate 
Set DateRangePointer = DateRangePointer.Item(2, 1)
```

Unless I've missed the point of your question?